# MS Dynamics CRM 2016 - Force new tab/window when opening record

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Currently when you double click on a record in the subgrid it opens in the same page. Is it possible to force it to open in a new window/tab? CRM has its own click handler and does not user onclick events. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way to open a record in a new window is to right-click and choose Open in New Window.  Very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

For Dynamics CRM subgrids, I have used the following JavaScript resource and applied it to the appropriate column. This is for an account record, but it can be altered for any entity.

```
    function PopAccount() {
      //get Account GUID
      var AccountGUID = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("accountid").getValue()[0].id;
      if (AccountGUID != null) {
      //open Account form
      Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("account", AccountGUID)
      }
    }
```